# Needing information on cyberattack that occured

Tags: network, wifi, bluetooth

If someone hacks into your WiFi and comes through an unlocked networked and knows your password and IP address and learns the specs on all your devices, the computer and cellphones, the smart TV, are all these devices now compromised forever with his knowledge now of the specs on devices?

Also if you have bluetooth enabled and use the audio of your vehicle to play music can the hacker use the cellphone bluetooth and the audio of vehicles mac address and access it and turn up the volume to an explosive level?

This happened to me and then I was sent 6 photographs on my cellphone of the audio attack in volume on my vehicle.

Comment: Please try to ask one question at a time. Be specific about the devices involved, your observations, the investigation you already did, and your actual question.

Comment: How does knowing the spec of the devices mean that the devices are compromised?

Comment: How does a "hacker" boost the volume of your car? by connecting to the car. It sounds like you were in close proximity to someone in another car who sent you pictures and connected to your car's audio. No "hack" required. If it can't be that, then you are going to have to provide a lot more detail.